# Correct SQL index for Partition + Order to remove SORT

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a SQL Statement which i am trying to optimise to remove the sort operator

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY RuleInstanceId 
        ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC
   ) AS rn
FROM RuleInstanceHistoricalMembership
```

Everything I have read (eg. [Optimizing SQL queries by removing Sort operator in Execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001197/optimizing-sql-queries-by-removing-sort-operator-in-execution-plan)) suggests this is the correct index to add however it appears to have no effect at all.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyIndex ON dbo.[RuleInstanceHistoricalMembership](RuleInstanceId, [Timestamp] DESC)
```

[image]

I must be missing something as I have read heaps of articles which all seem to sugguest an index spanning both columns should solve this issue

Comment: What happens when you change the `select *` to `select RuleInstanceID, Timestamp`

Comment: @1_CR that makes it go away, do i need the index to cross all selected columns also?

Comment: With a `select *` it's basically a choice for the optimizer between a clustered index seek for every row of the non-clustered index and a full table scan - it's probably justified in opting for the latter. You could add all the other columns as "payload" onto the non-clustered index by way of "include" columns to avoid having to visit the clustered index but without knowing more about data volumes etc it's hard to know if this is a wise choice

Comment: @1_CR this is in a table which i expect to contain hundreds of millions of rows and has 5 columns (long guid int bit datetimeoffset), is there another alternative to this?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor how much data is currently in the table?

Comment: 60M  rows at the moment

Comment: Also does your query really need to bring back all 60 million rows? Or just a paginated subset?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Technically the index you have added *does* allow you to avoid a sort.

However the index you have created is non covering so SQL Server would then also need to perform 60 million key lookups back to the base table.

Simply scanning the clustered index and sorting it on the fly is costed as being considerably cheaper than that option.

In order to get the index to be used automatically you would need to either.

- Remove columns from the query `SELECT` list so the index covers it.
- Add `INCLUDE`-d columns to the index.

BTW: For a table with 60 million rows you may well find that even if you were to try and force the issue with an index hint on the non covering index you still don't get the desired results of avoiding a sort.

```
CREATE TABLE RuleInstanceHistoricalMembership
  (
     ID             INT PRIMARY KEY,
     Col2           INT,
     Col3           INT,
     RuleInstanceId INT,
     [Timestamp]    INT
  )

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyIndex
  ON dbo.[RuleInstanceHistoricalMembership](RuleInstanceId, [Timestamp] DESC)

/*Fake small table*/
UPDATE STATISTICS RuleInstanceHistoricalMembership 
                  WITH ROWCOUNT = 600, 
                       PAGECOUNT = 10 

SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY RuleInstanceId 
                               ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC ) AS rn
FROM   RuleInstanceHistoricalMembership WITH (INDEX = IX_MyIndex)
```

Gives the plan

[image]

With no sort but up the row and page count

```
/*Fake large table*/
UPDATE STATISTICS RuleInstanceHistoricalMembership 
                  WITH ROWCOUNT = 60000000, 
                       PAGECOUNT = 10000000
```

And try again and you get

[image]

Now it has two sorts!

The scan on the NCI is in `RuleInstanceId, Timestamp DESC` order but then SQL Server reorders it into clustered index key order (`Id ASC`) per [Optimizing I/O Performance by Sorting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2009/02/25/optimizing-i-o-performance-by-sorting-part-1.aspx).

This step is to try and reduce the expected massive cost of 60 million random lookups into the clustered index. Then it gets sorted back into the original `RuleInstanceId, Timestamp DESC` order that the index delivered it in.

Comment: Thanks heaps for this answer, I have a heaps better understanding of why SQL wasnt picking my index now, Much appreciated